# Is there any other way to convert LocalDateTime to OffsetDateTime (timezone specific)

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, java-8

I want to convert `LocalDateTime` in `IST` timezone to `OffsetDateTime` in System dependent timezone. As of now my system is in `UTC` timezone hosted in AWS EC2. `LocalDateTime` field is received as response from an API called internally in my Spring boot backend service. Before saving that field, I convert it to `OffsetDateTime` to maintain the zone offset. So, I have used the below method for conversion.

```java
localDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"))
.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
.toOffsetDateTime();
```

**Input**: 2020-03-24T21:25:41 -> `LocalDateTime` in `IST`

**Output**: 2020-03-24T15:55:41Z -> `OffsetDateTime` in `System timezone (UTC)`

Is there any other way to do this conversion or it is the best way. Please help me on this.

Comment: On JDK-14 the `LocalDateTime` prints `2020-03-25T10:59:07.289253` and `OffsetDateTime` prints `2020-03-25T10:59:07.289253+05:30`. Isn't that what you expect?

Comment: @Naman what is timezone in your machine or the machine running JDK14?

Comment: It is `id="Asia/Kolkata"`. I got it, missed that the instance is in `UTC`. But then `OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = localDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"))
                .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
                .toOffsetDateTime();` doesn't help you?

Comment: I want conversion should be system dependent...like IST to wherever the system runs. That's the reason I'm going for `ZoneId.systemDefault()`

Comment: The output that you've mentioned in the question is not an `OffsetDateTime`, is that what you expect still? It might be good to edit reading that you want to convert `LocalDateTime` of one zone to another.

Comment: When I run `OffsetDateTime.now()` in my `UTC` machine, it gives `Z` only. Output: `2020-03-25T06:08:41.786Z`

Comment: What you're doing seems the best way, except maybe that you should start with `atZone(...)` instead of `atOffset(...)` to correctly handle DST of the input value.

Comment: Hmm. Seems right. Can you post it as answer?